# Swift - Customizing UISearchBar design programmatically

Tags: swift

I'm trying to customize UISearchBar design programmatically. I tried adding a bunch of codes but only a few places are changed.

This is the design I want to create.

[image]

And this is how it looks now.

[image]

*I screen-captured the second image from the simulator so it's bigger.*

Anyways, I'm trying to make my search bar has

1. Lighter background color
2. Shorter textfield in height
3. Textfield to have less corner radious

Here are my codes:

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 60))

    [In viewDidLoad()]
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.isTranslucent = false
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search the phrase"
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.73, green:0.76, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)
    searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "search"), for: .search, state: .normal)

    let forTextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    forTextField?.textColor = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.31, blue:0.31, alpha:1.0)
    forTextField?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 14)
    forTextField?.clipsToBounds = true
    forTextField?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    forTextField?.frame.size.height = 30
```

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the way you can achieve that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 60))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search the phrase"
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.73, green:0.76, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)

        //1. Lighter background color
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xE6E6E6)

        self.view.addSubview(searchBar)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        for subView in searchBar.subviews  {
            for subsubView in subView.subviews  {
                if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField {
                    var bounds: CGRect
                    bounds = textField.frame

                    //2. Shorter textfield in height
                    bounds.size.height = 28
                    textField.bounds = bounds

                    //3. Textfield to have less corner radious
                    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5 //Probably you can play with this and see the changes.
                    textField.clipsToBounds = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int, a: Int = 255) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(a) / 255.0)
    }

    convenience init(netHex:Int) {
        self.init(r:(netHex >> 16) & 0xff, g:(netHex >> 8) & 0xff, b:netHex & 0xff)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works except "textField.layer.cornerRadius". When I set it to 2 or 3, the corners are still round.

Comment: Yes I have checked that its not working for that minimum value. May be its a bug or limitation or something. @coonie

Comment: Thank you. Also I noticed when I use the codes you provided, my offset of the scope icon changes from the second visit of the search page. I think the problem is in the viewDidAppear section but I can't point it out. Do you why? Here's my code.  
        searchBar.setPositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 8, vertical: 1), for: .search)

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to add pictures in the comment section so I put those in your reply just for now. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share demo project of this?

Comment: I added my sample code in your post. Would this work? I've never shared a demo project so I don't know if this works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161643/discussion-between-richie-rich-and-coonie).